# Как импортировать пользовательскую библиотеку python в vs code, чтобы pylance "видел" её вместе с аргументами функций?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, импорт, library, pylance

### Кратко о проблеме:

- **Я хочу**, чтобы моя пользовательская библиотека на языке `python` была в одном единственном экземпляре (чтобы в случае изменений мне не приходилось копировать её во все другие расположения) и лежала по адресу `C:\Users\admin\MHCD\GitHub\Vova_Gary_and_Me\mhcd_functions\custom_library`.
- При этом **я ожидал**, что видел бы в VS Code подсказки `pylance` при вводе аргументов функций из этой библиотеки, подобные тем, что появляются при вводе аргументов функций стандартных библиотек, типа `pandas`, `openpyxl` и т.п.
- Вместо этого **я получил** "криво" импортированную, но рабочую пользовательскую библиотеку. Её функции выполняются при запуске блокнотов (`.ipynb`-файлов), но желанных подсказок от `pylance` я не получаю.
- **Сообщения об ошибках**, которые я наблюдаю:

  - > Import "mhcd_library" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
  - > "any_function_from_mhcd_library" is not defined Pylance reportUndefinedVariable

### Что я пробовал:

- Класть пользовательскую библиотеку непосредственно в каталог с блокнотом и импортировать её без использования модуля `sys` (весь код приведу ниже). Это решает проблему с `pylance`, но идёт вразрез с моими целями. Мне не нужно 100500 копий одной библиотеки.

### Что я не пробовал:

- Под сообщением об ошибке можно найти следующую подсказку:

  > add "C:\Users\admin\MHCD\GitHub\Vova_Gary_and_Me\mhcd_functions\custom_library" to extraPaths

  но я не знаком с `extraPaths`, поэтому не стал пробовать.

### Минимально необходимый код:

```py
# начало блокнота с использованием модуля `sys`, папка с блокнотом
# "C:\Users\admin\MHCD\", целевой файл
# "C:\Users\admin\MHCD\GitHub\Vova_Gary_and_Me\mhcd_functions\custom_library\mhcd_library.py":

import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\admin\MHCD\GitHub\Vova_Gary_and_Me\mhcd_functions\custom_library')
from mhcd_library import *

a = any_function_from_mhcd_library(parameter_1=1, parameter_2=2)


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# начало блокнота без использования модуля `sys`, папка с блокнотом
# "C:\Users\admin\MHCD\", целевой файл
# "C:\Users\admin\MHCD\mhcd_library.py":

from mhcd_library import *

a = any_function_from_mhcd_library(parameter_1=1, parameter_2=2)


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# начало пользовательской библиотеки "mhcd_library.py":

def any_function_from_mhcd_library(parameter_1, parameter_2):
    res = parameter_1 + parameter_2
    return res
```

Comment: Удобнее всего - превратить вашу библиотеку в пакет, и установить ее через `pip install -e .` (нужно запускать из папки, где лежит ваш пакет, либо указывать полный путь вместо точки), тогда она будет доступна по простому импорту без костылей типа `sys.path.append`.